# Snippet editor not working properly during text select/delete/copy/paste

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, editor

I had to rewrite my snippet on a post multiple times using the snippet editor, because it looks a bit broken:

The text I am selecting does not always correspond to the actual text, so after deleting this text for instance, the affected text is not the one I selected, but also other lines, so I am deleting text that I don't want to.

To reproduce the bug: Just create a snippet, go to the HTML panel for example, and start editing, selecting text, removing it. You will see the bug.

It was tested in Chrome and Firefox, and I manually resized my browser window (this works for jsfiddle chrome bug), but without any luck.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what the bug is or how to reproduce.

Comment: No repro on Chrome Win 10.

Comment: I am using macOS Sierra on a macbook pro, I don't know why you cannot reproduce it. Also @downvoters please explain the downvotes

Comment: I just explained my downvote, one and two comments up.

Comment: So you assumed that this bug is not real and just comes from my imagination?

Comment: No, but I'm explaining that this bugreport is unclear for me and not reproduceable.

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes such things happen. Just reload the page to solve the problem.

1. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to undo unwanted action.
   Anyway, usually you can see something wrong before doing anything, just by visual signs.
2. <kbd>Save & insert into post</kbd>
3. Copy all markup of the answer to clipboard.
4. Reload the page or open same url in a new tab.
5. Paste the answer into the field.
6. Open snippet for editing.

For me it works.

By the way, sometimes same problem happens with jsfiddle.

PS: Chrome in Win7 and Win10.